# How to describe a person that is slow to know people

Tags: meaning

How to describe a person that is slow to know people, in chinese we call it 慢
热。
Example when you meet new people , you tent to shy away and not talk much but when you get more familiar with the person you can be chatty.

Comment: *Shy or introvert*  may suggest that kind of attitude towards people you don't know.

Comment: 'shy' or 'introverted' mean quiet. There is no implication that eventually they will be much more talkative with you. The literal translation 'slow to warm up' makes sense (and is natural idiomatic English) but is not a set phrase or concept in that it is not a widely recognized type. So you can say very naturally 'That person is slow to warm up to you but eventually can become a very close friend', but briefer ways to say it will miss the nuances in the Chinese.

Answer (score 6):

If google-style translation can be trusted, the closes expression in English would be someone who is "slow to warm to" or "slow to warm up to" people.

From [*The Comprehensive Preschool Curriculum*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22slow%20to%20warm%20to%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl) by Albrecht and Miller:

> Fearful children avoid new situations and are **slow to warm to** new
>   people and experiences.

while [*The Essentials of Pediatric Nursing*](https://books.google.com/books?id=gqECBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT186&dq=%22slow%20to%20warm%20up%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEUQ6AEwB2oVChMI2ObzyMnwxgIVBHE-Ch29JACB#v=onepage&q=%22slow%20to%20warm%20up%20to%22&f=false) by Kyle and Carman prefers

> Some toddlers may be very **slow to warm up *to*** people they do not
>   know.

Comment: if i say i am slow to warm up to new people to a British guy, will he understand me ? slow to warm , is like a direct translation from Chinese, where i believe most Chinese will probably understand, not sure about westerner

Comment: Other ways are to say that someone has a *retiring* or a *retreating* personality.

Comment: It's used in an exercise in *The New Cambridge English Course 4*, so yeah, I think Brits will understand you.

Comment: @for ttest: It would definitely be understandable! I think this may be one of the very few situations where a direct translation is how you would actually say it in English. (Or British English at least anyway.)

Comment: This is a common, well-understood expression in American English as well.

Answer (score 1):

As a fellow Mandarin-speaker, I understand what you mean, but I cannot think of a one-word answer that conveys the same nuances of slowness and warmth. However, I think "reserved" would probably work for every day usage if "shy" doesn't do the trick.

Here is the relevant definition Google provides for "reserved":

> Reserved (adj) - slow to reveal emotion or opinions

Reserved is not quite as commonly used as shy, but I doubt anyone will give you a strange look if you use it. If anything it is a little more formal. Here are some examples:

> He is very reserved.
>
> He is a reserved man.

Do note that "reserved" also has other common definitions.

Comment: reserved to me means more of 保守。

Answer (score 1):

In British English we'd often term this as ***opening up***: this person ***takes a while to open up***.

However, often, we don't like to make explicit assertions about someone's character, instead we simply say that it ***takes a while to get to know them***.

Learning about someone and their personality is often termed ***getting to know*** them.

The meaning being conveyed is that it takes a while for that person to open up, but we're not saying so explicitly and thereby we're avoiding blaming said person. It's just a more polite, less accusatory way of saying it.

This is a very common way of expressing this in Britain - it's  uncommon to say 'he's introverted' or 'he's quiet'; we'd rather imply it.

Answer (score 1):

Like a tortoise (or turtle), a shy or meek person may retreat in their shell whenever they are feel threatened or intimidated by a social event or gathering. There is a very common idiom which is often used to describe the timid nature of this person.

> [**come out of one's shell**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shell)
>
> Fig. to become more friendly; to be more sociable.
>     •*to become less shy and more friendly*
>   •*to stop being shy and begin to confidently show your real character and feelings*
>      <sub><sup>*The Free Dictionary* and *Macmillan Dictionary*</sup></sub>
>
> *“Tom used to be very withdrawn but he's really come out of his shell since Susan took an interest in him.”*

The OP could say about himself:

***Once I've come out of my shell, I can be quite chatty.***

Answer (score 0):

You might say that the person is/was "**initially a bit tentative**" in engaging others.

Answer (score 0):

You could say :

- He is shy of new friends.
- He is slow in getting along with new friends

And the one-word answer that barely matches the meaning you want might be :

- (n.) He is an introvert.
- (adj.) He is so introvert.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**[icebreaker:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/icebreaker)** A thing that serves to relieve inhibitions or tension between people.

**[break the ice:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ice#ice)** Do or say something to relieve tension or get conversation going in a strained situation or when strangers meet.
*'Jenny is quite hesitant when it comes to **breaking the ice** at parties.'*

Answer (score 0):

A word that describes shyness, but with definite warmth underneath is "Bashful". Doesn't have quite the same sense of detachment or aloofness that many of the others do.